# Unable to display slice of structs in html

Tags: html, go, web, web-development-server

I am working on a project which requires me to retrieve data and display it on a html.

The data is stored and pass to the html as slice of structs.

The data consists of different fields (eg. name, temperature, humidity ...)
The data retrieval part is working (I have confirm by printing it out and displaying the Go slice on my html).
However, what I want to achieve is displaying the data properly in a table according to their fields. I have attached my code and there isn't any output. I couldn't find the errors.

Please help me with this. Thank you

*P.S All the names/labels are spelled correctly.

[image: This is the screenshot of the output]

This is the code:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
        {{if .}}

        <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr style="text-align: center;">
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Temperature</th>
                    <th scope="col">Humidity</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ambient</th>
                    <th scope="col">Red</th>
                    <th scope="col">Green</th>
                    <th scope="col">Blue</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>



        {{range .}}

        <tr style="text-align: center;">

          <td>{{.time_added}}</td>
          <td>{{.name}}</td>
          <td>{{.temperature }}</td>
          <td>{{.humidity }}</td>
          <td>{{.ambient }}</td>
          <td>{{.red }}</td>
          <td>{{.green}}</td>
          <td>{{.blue}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{end}}
    </tbody>

  </table>
    {{else}}
        <h1 style="font-size: 3vh;margin-top:10vh;">No data available</h1>
    {{end}}



  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you share the code that generates the template: what is in `.`. Also, and very importantly, and the `<tr>`'s being generated - if they are empty, they won't appear in the browser's display, but they might be there. So perhaps add a `<td>Hello</td>` to each row to see whether you have a table of `Hello`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the issue is that you are referring to the fields of your struct by lower-case names. In Go, lower-case is private, so there's no way for the template engine to see them.

Here's a simple, working example:

package main

```
import (
    `html/template`
    `os`
)

var T = template.Must(template.New(``).Parse(`
        {{if .}}
        <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr style="text-align: center;">
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

        {{range .}}
                <tr style="text-align: center;">
                  <td>{{.Time_Added}}</td>
                  <td>{{.Name}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{end}}
            </tbody>
          </table>
    {{else}}
        <h1 style="font-size: 3vh;margin-top:10vh;">No data available</h1>
    {{end}}
`))

type S struct {
    Time_Added string
    Name string
}

func main() {
    data := []*S{
        &S{"today","fred"}, &S{"yesterday","joe"},
    }
    if err := T.Execute(os.Stdout, data); nil!=err {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

If you change to `.time_added` or `.name`, you will get an error. So be sure to check for an error from `T.Execute`.